# Add fucntion call to WicketStuff Spinner properties

Tags: java, properties, spinner, wicket-1.5, wicketstuff

How do you put a function call to the java.util.Properties' `onIncrement`,
`onDecrement`, `afterUpdate` or `onStop` property of WicketStuff's Spinner configure method? I tried the following but the function is not called:

```
TextField<String> textField = new TextField<String>("textField ", new Model<String>("0"));
textField.add(new Spinner() {
    @Override
    protected void configure(Properties p) {
        super.configure(p);
        p.put("afterUpdate", "foo()");
    }
});

void fun() {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
}
```

The Javadoc for these properties is:

> onIncrement Function to call after incrementing
>   onDecrement Function
>   to call after decrementing
>   afterUpdate Function to call after update
>   of the value
>   onStop Function to call on click or mouseup
>   (default=false)

Note that when setting other properties everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/034ab2b1363d1f81609fec8362d8a80beb163227/minis-parent/minis/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/minis/behavior/spinner/Spinner.java#L164-L192 I don't see how this could work.
It iterates over the values from the Properties and checks their type. The **else** clause is what should cover your case. But the problem is that java.util.Properties can hold only String keys and values, so it will always go in the **if** clause, never in the **else if** and the **else**.

This code needs some improvements!
Feel free to create an issue and send a Pull Request!